# MikTex, multicol and Markdown on Windows with utf-8

Tags: xetex, miktex, markdown

I tried to create for myself usefult template for writing an articles using XeLaTeX and Markdown.
For this goal I have installed MikTex 2.9 on my computer and created a such template:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[scale=2.0]{ccicons}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\setmainfont{Roboto}
\markdownSetup{
  renderers = {
    link     = {#1},        % Render a link as the link label.
    emphasis = {\emph{#1}}, % Render emphasis using `\emph`.
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{markdown}

_Hello,_ [Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com)!

\end{markdown}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

But when I tried to compile it I got the following error:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"))
(untitled-mym.out) (untitled-mym.out)

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

*geometry* detected driver: pdftex

! Package markdown Error: I can not access the shell.

See the markdown package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.36 \end{markdown}
```

I suppose that this is relatex to xelatex settings on my computer.
How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

- Process the document with `lualatex`.
- Process the document with `xelatex` with the option `-shell-escape`. Alternatively, if you don't need the package `fontspec`, you can also use `pdflatex` with this option.

If I run either of the following commands

```
lualatex test.tex
xelatex -shell-escape test.tex
pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex
```

on `test.tex` containing the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\markdownSetup{
  renderers = {
    link     = {#1},        % Render a link as the link label.
    emphasis = {\emph{#1}}, % Render emphasis using `\emph`.
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}

_Hello,_ [Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com)!

\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

I get the following output:

[image]